# Data Transformation in Oracle

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g

What query should use, If I have a data set that I want to transform

```
From | To | Val1 | Val2 | Val3
123 130 AB  DE  EF
131 140 WS  ED  RF
141 145 GT  HY  JU
```

and I want to print the following data set in Oracle

```
ID | Val1 | Val2 | Val3
123 AB  DE  EF
124 AB  DE  EF
125 AB  DE  EF
126 AB  DE  EF
127 AB  DE  EF
128 AB  DE  EF
129 AB  DE  EF
130 AB  DE  EF
131 WS  ED  RF
132 WS  ED  RF
133 WS  ED  RF
134 WS  ED  RF
135 WS  ED  RF
136 WS  ED  RF
137 WS  ED  RF
138 WS  ED  RF
139 WS  ED  RF
140 WS  ED  RF
141 GT  HY  JU
142 GT  HY  JU
143 GT  HY  JU
144 GT  HY  JU
145 GT  HY  JU
```

Comment: you can loop this in pl, simple cycles

Comment: @access_granted - "never do in PL/SQL what can be done in plain SQL." Looping in PL/SQL will take much longer than a SQL statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assumptions: Your table is called `inputs` (if not, use your actual table name); the first two columns are called `f` and `t` (they **can't** be called `from` and `to`, those are Oracle reserved words); and the `f` column is unique - meaning, it has no duplicates - and you guarantee that `f <= t` in all rows:

```
select f + level - 1 as id, val1, val2, val3
from   inputs
connect by level <= t - f + 1
       and prior f = f
       and prior sys_guid() is not null
;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is really helpful.